# Unexpected CPU spikes

Tags: sql-server-2008

Im working with SQL Server 2008 R2. In development environment time to time i can see that CPU is under load for couple of minutes (*around 55%-80% while normal is 1-2%. yes really- normal load in my development environment is almost none!*). During this CPU pressure time automated tests sometimes gets timeout errors.

Just experienced timeout in activity monitor. looks like this:
[image]

Tipicaly during these pressure moments its looks like this:
[image]

Problem is that i cant understand why it is happening! There is continuously executed automated tests, but they are not making heavy workload. During performance tests system works good and if it slows down there is always good explanation for that.

Im trying to resolve issue by

- Running trace, but during those CPU spikes there is "nothing special" going on. No expensive queries.
- Using SQL Activity Monitor- everything seems normal, except CPU (just like 1-2 waiting tasks, low I/O, ~5 requests/sec). Recent expensive queries are not that expensive.
- Querying data. Using famous sp_WhoIsActive and sys.dm_exec_requests. As far i understand- nothing unusual again..

About my server

- There is small number of databases and i do know them good.
- Using Service Broker.
- Trace is running most of the time.

I do suspect that it is some background process that is making problems. But i dont really get it.. Can you please give some hints/ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Perhaps it can be Autogrowth on your database files that occasionally kicks in?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson database grows slowly and there is space enough. db's are in simple recovery model.

Comment: yes but the allocation process is done at one specific point in time. If your DB is set to grow by 10Gb each time it reaches its limit, this could be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It could be some internal SQL Server job. Like a big index rebuild.

Wait for the spike and `run sp_who2 'active'`. Check the column CPU Time.

Actually, how are you 100% sure that SQL is the responsible? Couldn't it be a SO issue?

Comment: Resource monitor on SQL Server machine shows, that the one utilizing CPU is "sqlservr.exe". there is no scheduled index rebuilds on this machine. Actually there is only scheduled backup job that runs every hour, but CPU spikes cannot be because of them.

Comment: There is bunch of system processes with last batch time 05/12 03:17:45 (it more looks like SQL Server start time) and 3 user processes- none of those 3 three are CPU expensive.

Comment: is the database being used by any application? Can you try setting a trace to look for deadlocks?

Comment: deadlocks being captured by using event notifications.. had one this morning, but its cannot be guilty.. Whats about Max memory setting of SQL Server? I just found out it had way too high values. Could it cause problems like this?

Comment: no, I dont see how max memory could cause the problem you are stating

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issues, and have raised case with Microsoft.

Microsoft guy told there is no issue from SQL DB side , if  cpu is spiked. Finally issue is resolved by Microsoft , actually issue was that on IIS, not SQL Server.

Every 29 days IIS need to be restart, So that you will get better performance on Application.